# Add class to selected radio button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

How do I add and remove a class only to selected radio button of a set of radio buttons?

```
<table class="radioClass" role="set1"><tbody><tr><td><input type="radio" value=" Yes " id="" name="j_id0:j_id37:j_id41"> label for="j_id0:j_id37:j_id41:0">  Yes </label></td><td><input type="radio" value=" No " id="" name="j_id0:j_id37:j_id41"<label for="j_id0:j_id37:j_id41:1">  No </label></td></tr></tbody></table>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("input[type='radio']").click(function(){
        var radioValue = $("input:checked").val();
       if(radioValue){
            //alert("Your are a - " + radioValue);
            $("input:checked").toggleClass("checked");
        }
    });
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8gwf2bx6/).

Comment: please check this: https://jsfiddle.net/8gwf2bx6/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First remove `checked` class from all radio buttons and then add to specific selected one. This is how you can do this:

```
if(radioValue){
     $("input[type='radio']").removeClass("checked");
     $(this).toggleClass("checked");
}
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/8gwf2bx6/2/)

Answer (score 0):

There should be no need to add a class. If you want to style the selected radio button or access it using jQuery simply use the `:checked` pseudo selector. More reading is available in the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/) and at [W3C](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_checked.asp).

However, if you still want to do this using an extra class for some reason, this should do it:

```
$("input[type=radio]").change(function() {
    //Whenever a radio button is changed.
    //Using click will not catch cases where it is changed for other reasons than clicks.
    $("input[type=radio]")
        .removeClass("checked")  //Remove the class from all elements.
        .filter(":checked")      //Filter out the checked ones.
        .addClass("checked")     //Add the class to those.
});
```